# Disable bash completion but only for a single argument position

Tags: bash

Maybe this isn't possible, since I'm limited to Bash 3.2 (which comes with MacOs), but I would like to disable completion at a single argument position, because it makes no sense to complete anything and I don't want filesystem completion.

I've got very close to this by returning an empty string in a list in COMPREPLY

```
_foo()
{
    if [[ $COMP_CWORD == 1 ]]
    then
        COMPREPLY=("aaa")
    else
        COMPREPLY=("")
    fi
    return 0;
}

complete -o default -F _foo foo
```

But this moves the cursor forward by one space whenever I press TAB.  If I provide an empty list:

```
COMPREPLY=()
```

It then completes on the directory files, which I don't want.  I guess I can live with this, but it would be nice if there was no completion *and* no cursor movement.

Comment: So `COMPREPLY=()`. You are returning one empty string, so it's completing one empty string. Return no strings.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, you might expect that but did you try it?  (with Bash 3).

Comment: Remove `-o default`. Did you read what `-o default` does :p ? `It then completes on the directory files, which I don't want.` Then don't `-o default`. You can also remove it with `shopt -u default`. Btw, you could potentially do `COMPREPLY=(""); shopt -s nospace` but that wouldn't be nice.

Comment: Oh dear!  Obvious when you point it out.  I should perhaps just delete this question, what do you think, is it useful?  I'm not so sure now.

Comment: I think feel free to post an answer and accept it ; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by KamilCuk (thanks) I had copy-pasted some code including the `-o default` argument to complete without understanding what it did.  The correct code is:

```
_foo()
{
    if [[ $COMP_CWORD == 1 ]]
    then
        COMPREPLY=("aaa")
    else
        COMPREPLY=()
    fi
    return 0;
}

complete -F _foo foo
```